# Range TS idioms and the mysterious auto &&

Tags: c++, c++20

In pre-Range TS code, I might do something like the following to get a (potentially modifiable) reference to a ForwardIterator's value:

```
auto &val = *it;
```

This would also be used in range-based `for` loops over such iterators:

```
for(auto &val : some_range)
```

However, in C++20 and Range TS-based code, I'm seeing a lot of `auto&&` usage in these locations. I understand what `auto&&` is doing from a language standpoint. What I don't understand is why it's being used in these places, when `auto&` ought to work just fine? Most code of this nature isn't forwarding the reference, so why is it using a forwarding reference to capture it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This idiom is being used because the Range TS and the C++20-equivalent actually *requires* this idiom. The reason for this requirement has to do with the fact that proxy iterators are now legal constructs for all categories of iterators.

A proxy iterator's `operator*` does not return a `value_type&`; it returns a prvalue of an object that *acts* like an reference. Therefore, if you tried to store a reference to the value with `auto&`, your code would fail to compile with a proxy iterator.

The Range TS's iterator concepts never require that the return value from `operator*` is actually a language reference. The Readable concept only requires that the return value is convertible to a `value_type`. The Writable concept only requires that a `value_type` can be assigned to the return value.

So code getting references from iterators of all kinds under the Range feature must now use `auto&&`, which can bind to prvalues without making them `const`. So when dealing with ranges, if you want to get a possibly non-const reference to the value, `auto&&` is the most convenient way. If you want just a `const` reference, you can continue to use `const auto &`.

---

Note that `auto&&` also handles iterators that directly return prvalues of type `value_type` from their `operator*`. Obviously these are only useful for Readable iterators, but they're quite useful. The simplest example would be an iterator for a counting range over some number of integers. The iterator returns an `int`, not a reference to some memory. Such iterators can be RandomAccessIterators in the Range TS due to not having a hard requirement for returning a language reference.

Such iterators would also make sense for regular expression matching. The current `regex_iterator` returns a reference to an internal object; that's necessary for being a ForwardIterator. Instead, it could have been much smaller by having `operator*` do the search and return the match object as a prvalue. But the old system wouldn't allow that.

Given such an iterator, `auto&` cannot be used to capture "references" to their results.

Comment: This might have been a good idea in C++11 to C++17 anyway: "output iterator" never did require `reference` to be an actual reference (though "forward iterator" did). So it's useful for an algorithm that would otherwise work with output iterators.  And since it's more general, it's easier to just make `auto&&` a habit rather than remembering when to use which.

Comment: Technically, Ranges are still only a "potential C++20" feature - the proposal is on track, but hasn't yet been merged into the working draft. "except for contiguous, but the Range TS and C++20 feature doesn't define that iterator category" - LEWG approved [P0944 "Contiguous Ranges"](http://wg21.link/p0944) in Rapperswil, it's now a part of the omnibus proposal that's in LWG. "it returns a prvalue of an object that acts like an iterator" You probably meant to say "reference" here.

Comment: Last but not least, I don't consider iterators whose reference operator returns a prvalue of the iterator's *value type* to be "proxy iterators." I prefer to refer to that class as "prvalue iterators." They also require using `auto&&` or `const auto&` to bind to the result of a dereference, but don't involve the other machinery (`iter_move`, `iter_swap`) that "true" proxy iterators require to workaround the lack of support for "smart references" in C++.

Comment: Oh: and I should also point out that it's not strictly necessary to use a forwarding reference. Given an iterator `it`, `std::iter_reference_t<decltype(it)> foo = *it;` is always valid. So even the heathens who hate `auto` can use Ranges ;)

Comment: @Casey: P0944 is useful, but I find it highly annoying that the `data` customization point can be used to get a pointer to the beginning of a contiguous range, but you cannot get a pointer to a contiguous iterator position at all. Not unless it is dereferencable, and the principle purpose of iterator-to-pointer conversion is to find a way to do it without needing the iterator to be dereferenceable. Also, why aren't ContiguousRanges required to be SizedRanges?

Comment: To my understanding, adding a customization point to retrieve the corresponding address from a contiguous iterator has been contentious in past WG21 discussions, I think in part because it would mean that pre-existing contiguous iterators wouldn't model the contiguous iterator concept. I chose to avoid the issue because I don't think there's a significant need: if you want pointers, take a contiguous range instead of an iterator and all is well.

Comment: I waffled back and forth a few times on requiring `SizedRange`, and finally decided that it's much easier for users to compose `ContiguousSizedRange` from the existing concepts than it is to decompose `ContiguousSizedRange` into `ContiguousUnsizedRange`.

Comment: @Casey: "*if you want pointers, take a contiguous range instead of an iterator and all is well.*" Unless of course you're dealing with an output iterator for which there is no need to have a paired iterator. Also, without making a `ContiguousRange` implicitly sized, to get a pointer *pair*, you now have to restrict it to a `SizedRange` too. So you can't just say `void foo(const ContiguousRange auto &var);`. You have to constrain it with two concepts, so you need a full template header and requires clause.