# Could std::vector<bool>::iterator implement its deref operator to return a reference to _Bit_reference?

Tags: c++, vector

Looping over `std::vector<bool>` in a *range-based-for* for altering the data, requires using either *forwarding reference* or just *value type*:

```
std::vector<bool> bv(5);
bool val = true;
for(auto&& b : bv) {
    b = val;
    val = !val;
}
```

Or:

```
std::vector<bool> bv(5);
bool val = true;
for(auto b : bv) {
    b = val; // yes, this alters the vector
    val = !val;
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
std::vector<bool> bv(5);
bool val = true;
for(auto& b : bv) {
  // ...
}
```

Above results with the known compilation error:

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::_Bit_reference&'
to an rvalue of type 'std::_Bit_iterator::reference'
  9  |     for(auto& b : bv) {
     |                   ^~
```

---

The question is whether, theoretically and practically, `std::vector<bool>` could implement `operator*` for its iterator, to return ***a reference*** to a `Bit_reference`?

This question came to my mind when implementing a naïve version of BoolArray, and being able to loop on a reference to my internal BoolProxy:

```
template<size_t SIZE>
class BoolArray {
public:
    // forward declaration
    class iterator;

private:
    char arr[(SIZE-1)/8 + 1] = {};

    class BoolProxy {
        char* const arr;
        size_t index;
        size_t byte_index() const {
            return index / 8;
        }
        size_t bit_index() const {
            return index % 8;
        }
        char bit_val() const {
            return 1 << bit_index();
        }
    public:
        friend class BoolArray<SIZE>::iterator;
        BoolProxy(char* const arr, size_t index): arr(arr), index(index) {} 
        operator bool() const {
            return arr[byte_index()] & bit_val();            
        }
        bool operator=(bool value) {
            if(value) {
                arr[byte_index()] |= bit_val();
            }
            else {
                arr[byte_index()] &= ~(bit_val());
            }
            return value;
        }
    };
public:
    class iterator {
        BoolProxy bp;
    public:
        iterator(BoolProxy bp): bp(bp) {}
        iterator& operator++() {
            ++bp.index;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator*() const {
            return bp;
        }
        // we return here a BoolProxy byref!
        // is there something wrong with it?
        auto& operator*() {
            return bp;
        }
        bool operator!=(iterator other) {
            return bp.arr != other.bp.arr || bp.index != other.bp.index;
        }
    };
    auto begin() {
        return iterator{BoolProxy{arr, 0}};
    }
    auto end() {
        return iterator{BoolProxy{arr, SIZE}};
    }
};

int main() {
    BoolArray<5> barr;
    bool val = true;
    for(auto& b : barr) { // looping on a reference here
        b = val;
        val = !val;
    }
    for(auto b : barr) {
        std::cout << b << ' ';
    }
}
```

It's true that the iterator is returned as an rvalue, but inside a range-based-for its lifetime would be extended, which should allow getting from it a reference to its internal BoolProxy.

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/8xjs16dKG

Comment: `auto& bit_ref = *it; it++;` and `bit_ref` is modified, which is not very intuitive.

Comment: @Amir: "*requires using either forwarding reference or just value type*" You should [get used to using `auto&&` in range code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51461281/734069).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<bool>` does not contain `Bit_reference` or any other such types. And `vector<bool>` is required to be a multipass range. This means that whatever `operator*` returns, it can't be a reference to something stored in the iterator, since you can increment the iterator and still access the `reference` the previous value of the iterator returned:

```
auto &&ref = *it;
++it;
//`ref` still references the previous bit.
```

This is where your proposed code fails.

So if `operator*` is to return a reference to an object... where is the object being *defined*? It can't be in the `vector<bool>`, and it can't be in the iterator. And it can't be defined within `operator*`, because then you'd be returning a reference to a local that will be destroyed once the function returns.

So where is it?

It has to be a temporary, an  object created within `operator*` itself and returned by value.