# Is flat_map an STL container?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, c++23

In the current draft of C++23s `flat_map` design, the type `flat_map::reference` is defined as `pair<const key_type&, mapped_type&>`, i.e. it is not a reference to `flat_map::value_type = pair<key_type, mapped_type>`.
(This seems to be mandatory, since the keys and values are stored not as pairs, but in two separate containers.)
Thus, the iterators must be some proxy-class.

This makes me think: Is a `flat_map` actually even an STL container, similar to `std::vector<bool>` isn't one?

Comment: The "STL" was/is a very old library (the Standard Template Library) that was incorporated into the C++98 standard library. Is any later thing added to the standard part of STL? No. Is it part of the standard library, yes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is true in a historical sense, but nowadays it gets more ambiguity. In the context of WG21 discussions, "STL" may denote [Stephan T. Lavavej](https://nuwen.net/stl.html), who is the maintainer of [microsoft/STL](http://github.com/microsoft/STL). The latter *is* an up-to-date implementation of the current ISO C++ standard library and IIRC Mr. STL strongly insists on that name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard defines what a "container" is in [container.reqmts]. Among these requirements [is](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.reqmts#lib:reference,containers):

> `typename X::reference`
>
> - Result: `T&`

So yes, `std::flat_map` is not a container.

But it never *claims* to be; it is [a "container adapter"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/flat.map#overview-1):

> A `flat_­map` is a container adaptor...

Note that like `std::stack/queue/priority_queue`, `std::flat_set/map` take container types as template parameters.

It should also be noted that, while they are not containers, they are *ranges* as defined by the C++20 range library's concepts. The C++20 ranges concepts [allow for proxy ranges where the `reference` type need not be a `value_type&`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51461281/734069).

Comment: The [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/flat.map#overview-2) says "A flat_­map meets all of the requirements of a container.". But it is not entirely accurate, is it? I'm feeling a bit uncertain about this claim in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Author of [P2767R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2767r0.html) here. This is all pedantic how-many-angels-can-dance-on-the-head-of-a-pin stuff, so while I'm going to present my *own* pedantic answer, please understand that I'm not claiming anyone else's different answer is necessarily wrong. It's *all* equally irrelevant in practice.

(1) `flat_map` itself (the class template) is not a container; it's a container adaptor. Even `vector` isn't a container; it's a template for stamping out containers. A "container adaptor," in my worldview, is a template for stamping out containers, where one of the template parameters is itself a container. Compare the usage of "iterator adaptor" (and "view adaptor" in Ranges). ["Class template `reverse_iterator` is an iterator adaptor,"](https://eel.is/c++draft/predef.iterators#reverse.iterators.general-1.sentence-1) but an object of type `reverse_iterator<int*>` is (simply) an iterator. `flat_set` is a container adaptor; an object of type `flat_set<int>` is (simply) a container.

Notice [[vector.overview]](https://eel.is/c++draft/sequences#vector.overview-1.sentence-1) doesn't say "***Class template*** `vector` is a sequence container..."; it says "***A*** `vector` is a sequence container..." That is, an object of type some-specialization-of-`vector` is (simply) a container.

> "But [[sequences.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/sequences#general-1.sentence-1) says, ‘*The headers `<array>`, `<deque>`, `<forward_list>`, `<list>`, and `<vector>` define class templates that meet the requirements for sequence containers!*’ How do you square that with your claim that class templates aren't containers?"
>
> Well, surely you agree that `<array>` doesn't define any class templates that meet the sequence-container requirements, right? We can argue about `vector<bool>`, but `array` *definitely* isn't a container. So that sentence is wrong on the face of it.
>
> (Meanwhile, TIL that C++23's [[vector.bool]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector.bool#pspc-8) implies that the user is allowed to provide "a program-defined specialization" for `vector<bool, A>`. Who knows *what* such a specialization might do!)

(2) As far as I'm concerned, `flat_map<int, int>` is a container. As you observed, [[flat.map]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/flat.map#overview-2.sentence-1) says explicitly that `flat_map` "meets all of the requirements of a container." Sure, on one hand it seems clearly to fail the `X::reference` requirement... but on the other hand, the standard *says* it meets *all* the requirements! Something's got to give; and I think it makes vastly more sense to assume that the C++98-era [container.reqmts] is out of sync with C++23's reality, than to assume that the C++23-era [flat.map] is out of sync. Someone just needs to update [container.reqmts] to handle the modern possibility of proxy reference types.

Comment: *Someone just needs to update [container.reqmts] ...* Thats a good point, but it also implies that we cannot really rely on the C++ standard. What's a container, meeting all the container requirements, worth then?
I may believed in the wrong concept that the standard is some kind of mathematical truth without errors (Which actually would make sense, since C++ is a language for deterministic computers).

Comment: "I may [have] believed in the wrong concept that the standard is some kind of mathematical truth without errors" — Oh yeah, absolutely not. Take it from a contributor: the Standard is just a paper document, written in English, that changes constantly (such that a new edition with major changes comes out every 3 years). Those who edit it have the goal of making it reflect the truth; but if it already *did* reflect the truth, there'd be no reason to edit it any more. :)