# Why do std::flat_set and std::flat_map have some noexcept functions while other container adapters don't?

Tags: c++, stl, noexcept, c++23

I noticed that `std::flat_set` and `std::flat_map` container adaptors provide some noexcept member functions, in particular there are the followings:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] bool empty() const noexcept;
size_type size() const noexcept;
```

However, all the other container adaptors provide the same member functions as non-noexcept:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] bool empty() const;
size_type size() const;
```

Is there a reason for this difference?

Comment: @273K containter adapters (`stack`,  and `queue` don't have `noexcept` or `constexpr` attributes, at least according to cppreference). But `flat_map` and `flat_set` are not container adapters.

Comment: A lot of the other container adapters existed before C++11 and the introduction of `noexcept`.  Most likely no one has made a proposal to add `noexcept` to them.

Comment: @ALX23z, _24.6 Container adaptors <queue>, <stack>, <flat_map>_ It is written in the proposal of `std::flat_map`.

Comment: @Los `stack` and `queue` simply use basic functionality of the container and push/remove elements with different named functions. `flat_set` and `flap_map` have a lot more requirements for the underlying containters to function.

Comment: @273K `flat_map/set`'s containers can be provided by the user.

Comment: @273K, _A flat_set is a container adaptor that provides an associative container interface that supports unique keys_  It is written in original proposal. Both `std::flat_set` and `std::flat_map` proposals essentially describe them as container adaptors. They are very different from `std::stack` or `std::queue`, but this does not change the fact they are container adaptors.

Comment: You are looking for an opinion based answer. You can make a proposal to C++ committee.

Comment: @273K, the standard describes them as container adapters. Also in Stack Overflow there was an accepted answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416249/is-flat-map-an-stl-container

Comment: This appears to be a defect in the standard.

Comment: @康桓瑋 no, it's backwards compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the noexcept specific to a function that is not guaranteed to be non-throwing can be dangerous. This problem occurs precisely with the `std::stack`, `std::queue` and `std::priority_queue` container adapters, which provide the `empty()` and `size()` member functions since C++98, and therefore did not force the underlying container's member functions to be non-throwing.

Comment: For both `flat_set`/`flat_map` and `stack`/`queue`/`priority_queue`, `empty()` and `size()` just call the underlying container's function. They're... the same. It doesn't make sense to argue that one is okay but the other is not.

Comment: @LoS How is this a problem? Calling a non-noexcept function from a noexcept-function is fine, as long as you are sure that the called function does not actually throw. Specification for std::vector::empty, as an example, does not specify any possible exceptions (see cppreference), so even if it is not marked as noexcept, it can be considered safe to call from "bool std::stack::empty() noexcept".

Comment: @Barry If you have a custom container where `MyContainer<T>::size()` can throw, adding `noexcept` to `std::queue::size()` breaks `std::queue<T, MyContainer<T>>`

Comment: "did not force implementers to use underlying container's member functions that be also non-throwing" -> "did not force the underlying container's member functions be non-throwing", `std::queue::size` [is defined as](https://eel.is/c++draft/queue.defn) `return c.size();`