# What is loki "Assoc Vector", how does it work, and how is it related to flat_map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, stl, containers

https://github.com/snaewe/loki-lib/blob/master/include/loki/AssocVector.h

Apparently this code was written by Andrei Alexandrescu.

There is a popular answer for benchmarking flat_map, but few details on how it works under the hood.

I can read the code, but I don't really understand everything, and I wish I could find some layman's.

flat_map might? will? be part of C++23, so I was curious about understanding its advantages and disadvantages, but I'm also curious to understand how it's implemented. Apparently is uses a map and a vector? What about an unordered version?

Is that somehow similar to an object pool, where an item removed in the middle of a vector is replaced with the last item of the vector to maintain contiguity? Is a flat_map somehow works like this with additional index tracking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is flat\_map an STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416249/is-flat-map-an-stl-container)

Comment: no it doesn't provide an answer (I picked "no" on the prompt)

Comment: It's fine to disagree. That's why we are voting. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first clue is in the declaration of the class:

```
class AssocVector
    : private std::vector< std::pair<K, V>, A >
```

This tells us that an AssocVector is just a vector of key-value pairs.

The second clue is right there in the constructor and a bit more implicit in the various operations:

```
AssocVector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, ...) {
    typedef ::std::map< K, V, C, A > TempMap;
    ...
    TempMap temp( first, last, me, tempAlloc );
    Base::reserve( temp.size() );
    BaseType & target = static_cast< BaseType & >( *this );
    MyInserter myInserter = ::std::back_inserter( target );
    ::std::copy( temp.begin(), temp.end(), myInserter );
}
```

This first constructs an `std::map` from the input and copies it **ordered by key** to the underlying vector.
Similarly, many operations use `std::lower_bound`, which requires the following:

> The range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the expression element < value (or comp(element, value)), i.e., all elements for which the expression is true must precede all elements for which the expression is false. **A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.**

Thus, an AssocVector is a vector of key-value pairs that are always sorted by key and cannot contain duplicate values for a given key, much like `std::map`.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes more sense now. So how does it keep this vector sorted at insertion? does it means it will move every element right of the inserted value? Does it mean it's slow at random insertion, but fast at "sorted insertion"?

Comment: Yes, `AssocVector::insert` calls `std::vector::insert` with all caveats that entails.

Comment: what about lookups? does it still uses an RB tree when querying keys?

Comment: No, it uses `std::lower_bound` which is a binary search.